# How to get block printed out with sed

Tags: sed, zsh

### The problem

I have the following input file:

`test.txt`

```
This is a text2
This is a text3
This is a text4
This is a text5
START
This is a text1
END
This is a text6
This is a text7
This is a text8
This is a text9
```

I'd like to print the text between the `START` and `END` block with `sed` to
practice with it a little bit but I'm so confused how to achieve that.

### What I've tried

I tried the following commands:

- `cat $(test.txt) | sed -n -e '{/START/=},{/END/=}p'`
  I hoped here that the `{/START/=}` and `{/END/=}` blocks return the line numbers
  where the `START` and `END` block are.
- `cat $(test.txt) | sed -n -e '$(sed -n -e "/START/="),$(sed -n -e "/END/=")p'`
  I tried to get the line numbers of the `START` and `END` blocks by embedding
  them into `$(...)`.

I'm getting out of ideas.

### What would you recommend to use for?

Anyways, I'm also wondering if using `sed` is the best tool for this task. Do you
have any suggestions for other tools which suit more for this task? I'd like to
see an example as well, thanks!

Comment: `sed -ne '/START/,/END/p' test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -ne '/START/,/END/p' test.txt
```

Is the typical solution.  This will apply the `p` command to all lines between (and including) line that matches START until the line that matches END.

Excluding the start and end of the range is not very clean in sed.  One approach is to explicitly match them:

```
sed -ne '/START/,/END/{/START/d; /END/d; p;}' test.txt
```

but for this particular use case it's probably cleaner to include those lines in the range of lines that are explicitly deleted:

```
sed -e '1,/START/d' -e '/END/,$d' test.txt
```

Comment: Wow... I think that I thought a little bit too complicated.... could you also add an example to get the text between `START` and `END` *excluding` `START` and `END`?